# Global database in Microsoft-Access

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access program to create and search data (it's an inner system for my work- without any connection to the internet, but we do have a local drive).
How can I make a global database for Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create a db with tables to be shared (the global db) and another db with forms, queries,reports,and code (the client db) . Make one copy of the shared db and put it on a shared drive on your LAN. You use the Access "link" feature to connect to the tables in the global db from the client db. The client db is then distributed to your users and resides on each of their local drives.